# I need help to put this script together

Tags: ftp, account

I have a API script for ftp Account creator. I'm not sure what am i doing wrong. There are 3 file there , one is config, one is function and the other is APi with account creator. after putting all file in the server it doesnt create the account. would anybody will help me out . Thank You

First config file

```
/* cPanel Options */
     $cpanel_user = " cpanel username";
     $cpanel_pass = "Cpanel password";
     $cpanel_domain = '127.0.0.1'; // if this doesn't work, you might not want to use it.
     $cpanel_skin = 'x3';
     $cpanel_default_ftp_quota = 5; // MB
```

$url = "http://$cpanel_user:$cpanel_pass@$cpanel_domain:2082/frontend/$cpanel_skin/";

2nd is Function

```
 function cPanel($action,$function,$args) {
         global $MESSAGES, $url;

     $url .= "$function?";
     $url_args = array();
     foreach($args as $key => $value) {
         $url_args[] = "$key=$value";
     }
    $url .= implode("&",$url_args);

    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($result === FALSE) {
        $status = 'error';
        $message = $result;
    } else {
        $status='success';
        $message=$MESSAGES[$action];
    }

    return array($status, $message);

    }
```

3rd file with account creation.

```
// the options mentioned in part one are set here
   include_once 'config.php';
   $url = "http://$cpanel_user:$cpanel_pass@$cpanel_domain";
 $url .= ":2082/frontend/$cpanel_skin/";

     if(isset($_REQUEST['format'])) {
         $format=$_REQUEST['format'];
     } else {
        $format='html';
    }

    // other stuff (including the emailUser function you'll see called below)

    function addUser($user,$pass,$email_address) {
        // we need to add the user to our database
        // for other purposes
    }

    function createAccount(
        $ftp_user, $ftp_pass, $email_address, $ftp_homedir, $ftp_quota) {
        global $base_dir, $source_dir;
        $error=addUser($ftp_user, $ftp_pass, $email_address);
        if (!$error) {
            $ftp_homedir .= $ftp_user;
            $copy_dir = $base_dir . $ftp_user;
            $cpanel_results = cPanel('signup','ftp/doaddftp.html',
            array('login'=>$ftp_user,'password'=>$ftp_pass,
            'quota'=>$ftp_quota,'homedir'=>$ftp_homedir)
            );
            $error = $cpanel_results[0];
            if ($error!='error') {
                recursive_copy($source_dir,$copy_dir);
            }
            if($error!='error') {
                    return emailUser($email_address,'signup','');
            } else {
                return $cpanel_results;
            }
        } else {
            return array('error', $error);
        }
    }

    $message = Null;
    if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']) ) {
        switch ($_REQUEST['submit']) {
            case $signup_button:
                $args = createAccount(
                $_REQUEST['username'],$_REQUEST['password'],
                $_REQUEST['email_address'],$_REQUEST['ftp_homedir'],
                $_REQUEST['ftp_quota']);
                break;
            // other cases snipped
            default:
                $args = array(Null,Null);
        }
        $message_class = $args[0];
        $message = $args[1];
    }

    if ($message) {
        if ($format!='html') {
            die($message);
        } else {
    $message="<div id=\"message\" class=\"$message_class\">$message</div>";
        }
    }

    // generate html form here
    // $message is included and styled to display
    // above the form in red (error) or green (success)
?>

 <head>
  <title>cPanel FTP Account Creator</title>
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
</head>
<body>
  <style>
    input { border: 1px solid black; }
  </style>
    <form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
     <label for="username">Username</label>
     <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username">
     <label for="password">Password</label>
     <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password">
    <label for="email_address">Email Address</label>
     <input type="text" name="email_address" value="" id="email_address">
     <input type="hidden" name="ftp_quota" value="5" id="ftp_quota">
     <input type="hidden" name="ftp_homedir" value="public_html/user_files/" id="ftp_homedir">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up" id="signup_submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can please any one help me out? thank you

Answer (score 0):

I won't go into detail but a quick glance, I see a couple of possible problems:

1) You might use special/reserved characters in the username or password so it is best to urlencode them before using it in the url

2) Some cPanels require sessions so you would have to insert the session id into the url as well.

3) Some cPanels are strict in cUrl calls. What I mean is you should have a "complete" curl call with the headers, cookies, etc... or else the cUrl won't work.